# How to access webcam in Safari and IE? Are there any alternative API to getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, getusermedia

I am currently accessing webcam in javascript, then streams to browsers using getUserMedia, caniuse.com shows that Safari and Internet Explorer 11 and above are not able to access getUserMedia.

I use this to check if there is a webcam,

```
navigator.getUserMedia  =   navigator.getUserMedia ||
                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                        navigator.msGetUserMedia;
```

Then I display using this :

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia){
//document.getElementById("webcam").style.display = "block";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        video = document.getElementById("video"),
        videoObj = { "video": true },
        errBack = function(error) {
            console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
        };

    // Put video listeners into place
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
            video.src = stream;
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
    else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
            video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
    else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, errBack);
    }
    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        canvasToDataURLString = canvas.toDataURL();
        var blob = dataURItoBlob(canvasToDataURLString);
        base64result = canvasToDataURLString.split(',')[1];
        //console.debug(base64result);
        document.getElementById("base64result").innerHTML = base64result;

    });
}, false);
```

}

Or there simply is no way of accessing webcam using IE and safari? I understand there are limitations in Chrome as the webpage has to be accessed from a secure origin.

I wonder if I am doing it wrongly...
I want to know if there are any other alternatives to getUserMedia!
Thank you and please be kind, I have already tried googling and nth much came out, I am just seeking for alternatives, if it is really impossible, then ok. 
Thank you !

Comment: First, navigator.getUserMedia is deprecated since years. Use navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia instead. Then Safari supports mediaDevices.gUM since v11. And for older browsers, the only way back then was to use flash, but you probably don't want to support these anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IE: no. fuggedaboudit. (the good news is that even older versions of Windows can now use new Edge, and as far as gUM and MediaRecorder go, it *is* Chromium.)

Safari, both mobile and mac, yes.  gUM works, but MediaRecorder is wakky.

These samples let you test what various browsers do, and you can use the source for guidance on your project.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/